# Issues installing pgsql extension for PHP 7.3.24 on Mac Big Sur using homebrew

Tags: php, postgresql, macos, php-extension, macos-big-sur

Does anyone know the commands to get the `pgsql` extension installed on a Mac? Trying to use Homebrew but no luck. I suspect the commands or way I'm trying to get the extension are incorrect.

I tried:

```
brew install php@7.3-pgsql
```

```
brew install php--with-pgsql[=DIR]
```

```
brew install php@7.3-pdo-pgsql
```

Current version of PHP: 7.3.24
Mac: Big Sur

Specifically need `pdo_pgsql` extension.

Comment: try to be a bit more explicit about `no luck` ... no one could offer any sort of advice/help with the description of the problem.

Comment: Maybe try this [link](https://gist.github.com/giorgiofellipe/6282df335fd310de4108) ? Note that: change PHP_VER with your PHP version.

Comment: It shows that I have pdo_mysql.. but I need pdo_pgsql.

Comment: try to brew php itself , something like this : `brew install php@7.3 --with-postgresql`

Comment: I could not install too, still waiting for a solution...

Comment: See fix below @ÂngeloPolotto

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: ISSUE SOLVED After Big Sur update homebrew needs upgrade (see article below):

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-upgrade-homebrew

Comment: Not a solution. Question is how to link the php with pgsql

Answer (score 0):

If you are using port to install the php versions.
Use below code to install pgsql or I can say postgres

> `sudo port install php81-postgresql`

This will work with me on macos 10.15.7 and php version 8.1
brew is taking too much time to compile and make package and installation.
port is far better then brew for php

reference link : https://ports.macports.org/port/php81-postgresql/